# Flutter Timer reduces after every next questions

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created a quiz app using Flutter and Laravel, Everything is working fine except for Timer.

The Time is reduced multiple times for question no. as

***Reduces means if I given 60 seconds for each question then in the first que. it is okay but in 2nd ques. it starting from 60 the 58 the 56 then 54 sec..***

and in 3rd, it starts from 60 then 57 then 54.. this way.

- first question timer reduces 1 second.
- in the second question, it reduces to 2 seconds.
- in the third question it reduces 3 seconds and
- after 10 questions it only is there for a few seconds

```
  int timer = 60; 
  String showtimer = "60";
  bool canceltimer = false;
```

**Here is the timer function**

```
void startTimer() async {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        if (timer < 1) {
          t.cancel();
          this.nextQuestion(context);
        } else if (canceltimer == true) {
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          timer = timer - 1;
        }
        showtimer = timer.toString();
      });
    });
  }
```

**And in the nextQuestion method, I am further calling showtimer function**

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code, but I suspect that you're accidentally creating an extra periodic `Timer` with each question (perhaps if you advance to the next question without cancelling or without the time running out).  If so, your Nth question would have N `Timer` callbacks that each decrement the remaining time by 1.  A more robust way to handle periodic `Timer`s is to store the `Timer` and to check for an existing `Timer` before creating a new one.

Comment: @jamesdlin Here is the full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JmJ0GN4SNy7In-hmRB0QDMahFw-IlY5P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Before I look at your code and do all of your debugging for you, have you considered and tried what I suggested?  If our timer callback always decrements the time only by 1 second, then if you're observing it decrement by more than 1 second, you logically must have more than one timer callback executing.

Comment: But sir, How it is possible to use more than one timer callback? Please take a look and suggest me.

Comment: If you don't cancel a periodic `Timer`, it will continue executing.  If you create a new periodic `Timer` without cancelling an existing one, you will have multiple `Timer`s. It is easy to verify if this is the problem: add a `debugPrint` statement to your `Timer` callback and see if it's called more than once per second.  Again, *you* should do this before expecting others to do all of the debugging for you.

Comment: `verifyAndNext` calls `nextQuestion`.  `nextQuestion` calls `startTimer`, and `startTimer` unconditionally creates a new periodic `Timer`.  At no point in this call chain does anything cancel any existing `Timer`. (And since you do not store a reference to the `Timer`, nothing *can* cancel an existing `Timer`.  The way you've written your code, each `Timer` can only cancel itself, but each `Timer` will cancel itself only after 60 seconds have elapsed or unless the `canceltimer` member is `true`.  However, you reset `canceltimer` to false when you create new `Timer` objects.)

Comment: @jamesdlin it started working sir, Now how can I accept your comment as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty classic symptom of accumulating multiple periodic `Timer`s: initially you'll see your callback triggered once per period, but eventually you'll see it called twice per period, and later three times per period, and so on.  This is easy to verify by adding `debugPrint` statements to your `Timer` callback.

Skimming over your code, when someone answers a question, `verifyAndNext` will start a new periodic `Timer` for the next question without cancelling the previous `Timer`.  As written, your code *can't* cancel the previous `Timer` because you've made each periodic `Timer` responsible for cancelling itself.

You want an invariant that there should be at most one periodic `Timer` active at any time.  You should enforce that.  One typical pattern is to save the periodic `Timer` somewhere (such as to a member variable) and to check whether a `Timer` already exists before creating a new one.  This would provide a strong guarantee that you never create multiple periodic `Timer`s that are simultaneously active:

```dart
  Timer? periodicTimer;

  void startTimer() async {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);

    periodicTimer?.cancel();
    periodicTimer = Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) {
      ...
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this, your initial time is `int timer = 60;`  so after first question u'll update `timer = 60`,

In updated timer you have to do  `timer = 60 - i` i is for question number like  i = 1,2,3 in this scenario timer will  reduces 1 second and depend on ur  question number. hope this logic will use for you.

Comment: Then I should update this in my nextQuestion method?

Comment: yes update the method.

Comment: if it is work then accept this, it's help to others

Comment: Not worked! Here is the full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JmJ0GN4SNy7In-hmRB0QDMahFw-IlY5P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: timer = timer - 1; here you need subtract questions number like,  timer - 1;  timer - 2;  timer - 3; so for this function pass questions position (Index)

Comment: This answer makes no sense, especially since it provides no justification for why it suggests that subtracting *n* seconds for the *n*th timer should be logical.